# Oracle handling m:n join table

Tags: oracle, join

Another case of a seemingly simple problem leaving me stumped: Oracle creates a surprising execution plan when performing a join via an m:n join table. I'm not saying, it is wrong but I would be happy for an explanation.

While investigating why a production application slowed down to a crawl I rewrote a query using a join table. This worked but the execution plans I' seen left me wondering. So I created an artificial testcase to help me understand the things I've seen.

The setup is simple: Two table, both having a generated primary key and some additional "payload" columns:

```
CREATE TABLE left_table
(
  id     NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
  value1 VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  ...
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE right_table
(
  id     NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
  value1 VARCHAR2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL,
...
);
```

And the join table:

```
CREATE TABLE left_to_right
(
   left_id   NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
   right_id  NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_left FOREIGN KEY (left_id) REFERENCES left_table(id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_right FOREIGN KEY (right_id) REFERENCES right_table(id)
);
```

Straight forward, right?

But here come the queries (left and right tables have been filled with 1,000,000 random values, the mapping tables contains 49,000 rows):

(a) Simple query just on the join table:

```
SELECT
 m.left_id,
 m.right_id,
 l.id     AS l_id,
 r.id     AS r_id
 --l.value1 AS lval
FROM LEFT_table l,
 RIGHT_table r,
 left_to_right m
WHERE m.left_id BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000
   AND m.left_id  = l.id
   AND m.right_id = r.id;
```

Selects an arbitrary range of left-table ids from the join table and the same ids from the join table. The execution plan is completely as expected: Oracle uses the key on the join table.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation    | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |          | 49265 |  1250K|   270   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| PK_LEFT_TO_RIGHT | 49265 |  1250K|   270   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(b) Adding elements from the left table
Now we add a column from the left hand table to the projection:

```
SELECT
  m.left_id,
  m.right_id,
  l.id     AS l_id,
  r.id     AS r_id,
  l.value1 AS lval -- <- added a row from the left table
FROM LEFT_table l,
  RIGHT_table r,
  left_to_right m
WHERE m.left_id BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000
AND m.left_id  = l.id
AND m.right_id = r.id
```

The execution plan

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name              | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                    | 22222 |  2278K|       |   680   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN                     |                   | 22222 |  2278K|       |   680   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | LEFT_TABLE        |   100K|  7739K|       |    42   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | SYS_C0010389      |   100K|       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   SORT JOIN                     |                   | 49265 |  1250K|  3496K|   638   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | PK_LEFT_TO_RIGHT  | 49265 |  1250K|       |   270   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would have expected that the database selects the appropriate rows from the join table and afterwards uses the index to access the left hand table. Instead, a sort join is used, pushing the overall costs.

(c) Adding a column from the right hand table:

```
SELECT
  m.left_id,
  m.right_id,
  l.id     AS l_id,
  r.id     AS r_id,
  l.value1 AS lval, -- <- column from left table
  r.value1 as rval --  <- column from right table
FROM LEFT_table l,
  RIGHT_table r,
  left_to_right m
WHERE m.left_id BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000
AND m.left_id  = l.id
AND m.right_id = r.id
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name         | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |          | 22222 |  3993K|   | 11821   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN            |          | 22222 |  3993K|  2544K| 11821   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN              |          | 22222 |  2278K|   |   680   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| LEFT_TABLE   |   100K|  7739K|   |    42   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SYS_C0010389     |   100K|   |   |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    SORT JOIN              |          | 49265 |  1250K|  3496K|   638   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | PK_LEFT_TO_RIGHT | 49265 |  1250K|   |   270   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL       | RIGHT_TABLE  |   958K|    72M|   |  6889   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the point where I stop understanding anything about joins: Adding a column from the right hand table causes the optimizer to select a **full table scan** on the well filled table (remember: 1,000,000 rows). This sends the execution costs through the ceiling although an index for a direct access would exist (and yes, I refreshed the database statistics).

While the execution is still fast enough for my purposes (the application is still able to read ~ 22,000 rows per second), I would like to understand why oracle uses a full table scan for the right hand table. In my naive understanding, a join via the primary key would be faster...
Who can explain this mystery to me?

Regards

Edit: I've done the same test using a postgresql database: The execution plan is much more than I would expect:
The primary keys of the left and right tables are used:

```
       Nested Loop  (cost=7072.76..53476.36 rows=48290 width=86)
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=7072.33..22497.73 rows=48290 width=49)
                Hash Cond: (m.left_id = l.id)
                ->  Seq Scan on left_to_right m  (cost=0.00..7549.00    rows=490000 width=12)
                ->  Hash  (cost=5070.45..5070.45 rows=98551 width=37)
                      ->  Index Scan using left_table_pkey on left_table l     (cost=0.42..5070.45 rows=98551 width=37)
                            Index Cond: ((id >= 100000) AND (id   Index Scan using right_table_pkey on right_table r     (cost=0.42..0.63 rows=1 width=37)
                Index Cond: (id = m.right_id)
```

Another update: Thanks for your answers. 
I pondered the comment posted by Evgeniy K. a bit and attempted the following:
I've added an index on columns id and value1 on right table. For the final query the execution plan changes as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name         | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |          |   147K|    27M|   | 22059   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                |          |   147K|    27M|    18M| 22059   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN               |          |   147K|    16M|  9112K|  2694   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| LEFT_TABLE   |   102K|  7906K|   |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN              | SYS_C0010428     |   100K|   |   |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN           | PK_LEFT_TO_RIGHT |   228K|  8716K|   |  1683   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN            | FOO      |  2959K|   222M|   |  5717   (1)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(please don't mind the increased row number: I've experimentally increased the table size to 3,000,000 rows for left_table and right_table. Basically the query still accesses all rows of the right_table)

So, the additional index will
(i) replace the full table scan with an index range scan
(ii) the costs are the same (all rows are accessed)
Therefore this index does not really help in this situation. Additional fun fact: The index is used also if I select another column from right_table not even in the index. My interpretation is that the index is used in a more or less arbitrary fashion, as the net effect of the index is zero.

Comment: You forgot to explain primary key PK_LEFT_TO_RIGHT.

Comment: this is the primary key on the join table: (left_id, right_id).

Comment: Also, post exact number of rows from all of the three tables.

Comment: left/right table: 1,000,000 rows, left_to_right mapping table: 490,000 rows picked evenly distributed.

Answer (score 1):

**In first query** CBO removes two tables from execution plan because all needed info it has already haved in index PK_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, so why you don't see any table access/index scans in any other table.

**Hint:** To see another table in plan try to remove fk or use left/right join

**In second query** SORT JOIN appeared because between operation. CBO assume that it would be cheaper get data throw index PK_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, sort them and then join instead use simple nl.

**In third query** you add column that not in index and CBO need table access that's why it use

```
 TABLE ACCESS FULL       | RIGHT_TABLE
```

Why it uses Hash join? Because LEFT_TABLE   is small and RIGHT_TABLE is huge then CBO decided use hash join. It cann't use index range on unique scan on  RIGHT_TABLE (probe table) due to mechanism of hj. Just look one more time how hj works.

**Little hint:** add smt like r.id = 10 and you see unique scan on hash join, like this:

```
HASH JOIN
  .....
  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID
     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN
```

Comment: Hm, why would it use a full scan when I select another column from the current row ? There is no restriction on the column... Furthermore. left and right table have the same size (1,000,000 records) But thanks for the answer

Comment: primary key index on LEFT_TABLE and PK_LEFT_TO_RIGTH index sorted in the same order so Merge join seems optimal

Comment: Yes, correct: If a pick a row directly via primary key, the execution plan is as expected: Right table is accessed via an index range scan instead of a full table scan.

Comment: @bahkauv Just because in second query all info gets from index and needn't go to RIGHT_TABLE. Then you decided get column r.value1 not from index and from another table then CBO must join table and visit blocks from table

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin Yes, you are right + inequlity operation(Instead it can use hj)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the optimizer calculates and decides that the cost of executing a seek and a disc access for each row is more costly than doing a table scan and then filtering the rows.

Remember that a full-table scan grabs more pages off disk in a single I/O read than a nested loop, which returns a single page. This full-scan behaviour is determined by the database system's `db_file_multiblock_read_count` parameter.

So, the optimizer decides that reading the entire table is **less costly** (not necessarily faster) and then filter the rows in memory rather than doing a table lookup for each row.

Also, a skew in the data which you are selecting might have an influence on choosing this execution plan.

*This is my 2 cents on the issue, so it might give you some insight on this, but it's definitely not a answer which covers every possible cause in full, there might be other elements which influence this behaviour.*

Comment: As the data is artificially generated it should be evenly distributed. For my test I just picked some arbitrary rows from the left/right tables and created the join table via a cartesian product. If it helps I can the post the boring statements for generating the tables.

Comment: @bahkauv No need, I don't have a Oracle db or terminal at my fingertips so I can't really take this and test it. I would have posted the information as a comment, but it was too long. Either way, I'm not sure if you were aware of the things I mentioned, but I think it's a good to know. Also, [**the source from where I know this is here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4hKomnGHFA&t=4470s) - Although I recommend watching the entire video.